# TypeError: UserModel.create is not a function, Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having some problem using Sequelize, this is my code:

index.js

```
import {initializeSequelize} from "./config/sequelize_init"

async function main() {
  try {

    let db = await initializeSequelize();

    console.log("DB Connected");

    app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");

      const UserModel = require('./api/v1/user/model')

      UserModel.create({fname: "a", lname: "a"});
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }
}

main();
```

sequelize_init.js

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

  export async function initializeSequelize() {

    const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.MYSQL_NAME, process.env.MYSQL_USER, process.env.MYSQL_PASS, {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
        operatorsAliases: false
      });


      const models = {
        User: sequelize.import('../api/v1/user/model.js')
      };

      Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
        if ('associate' in models[key]) {
          models[key].associate(models);
        }
      });

      models.sequelize = sequelize;
      models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

      let a = await models.sequelize.authenticate();

  }
```

model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define('user', {
          fname: Sequelize.STRING,
          lname: Sequelize.STRING
    });
}
```

This is the log when I start the server:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result (<<<--- I DONT KNOW WHAT IS THIS BTW)
DB Connected
Example app listening on port 3000!

UserModel.create({ fname: "a", lname: "a"});
                        ^

TypeError: UserModel.create is not a function
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think the script strucure not better, call all required models at the begining. you missed `;` as well at the end of `const UserModel = require('./api/v1/user/model')`, and did not understand, why do you use `Sequelize`.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you'd have to access the user model after requiring models.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you make an example from my code?

Comment: We register models in our sequelize object during the starting of the application.
By writing this

`const UserModel = require('./api/v1/user/model')` 

You are just requiring the models, you will have to access the user model specifically to perform DB operations on it.